# Get the specific data (seatType: & seatTypeId:) from an Array React

Tags: reactjs

I have an Array that has the following data & I want to get the specific attributes to variables which I need to pass through URL parameters.

Array

```
      MovieSeatList:[
        adultPrice: 350
        childAvailable: true
        childPrice: 280
        seatRows: [Array(5)]
        seatType: "ODC"
        seatTypeId: 536
       ]
```

code:

```
       render() {
        const {MovieSeatList, dataLoaded} = this.state;    
        
        console.log(MovieSeatList)
        // MoviedatatoPlan = MovieSeatList
        console.log(MovieSeatList)
        console.log(movieData)
}
```

It would be better if I can get the following attributes to variables that will be passed in URL parameters.
seatType:
seatTypeId:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let seatType = MovieSeatList.map(a => a.seatType);
let seatTypeId = MovieSeatList.map(b => b.seatTypeId);
```